# PHP preg_match check string with specific words

Tags: php, match

I want to check string contain only few specific words.

4bored4,4blur4,4blingeye4,4bathing4,4congratz4,4crisp4,4curse4, white space and dot.

here's my code

```
$s = '...... 4crisp4 4crisp4 4crisp4';

preg_match('/^[4bored4|4blur4|4blingeye4|4bathing4|4congratz4|4crisp4|4curse4| |\.]+$/',$s,$m);
```

but failed with this $s = 'hahahha 4crisp4 4crisp4 4crisp4';
why this string with hahahha word is ok with this pattern?

i want return failed if no specific words, dot , white space on this string.

Answer (score 0):

When using `^` means that you're only looking for it at the start of the string. And `$` means you're only looking for it at the end of the string.

This will work:

```
$s = '4crisp4 4crisp4 4crisp4';
preg_match('/^[4bored4|4blur4|4blingeye4|4bathing4|4congratz4|4crisp4|4curse4| |\.]+$/',$s,$m);
```

This won't work:

```
$s = 'asdf 4crisp4 4crisp4 4crisp4';
preg_match('/^[4bored4|4blur4|4blingeye4|4bathing4|4congratz4|4crisp4|4curse4| |\.]+$/',$s,$m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
preg_match('/[4bored4|4blur4|4blingeye4|4bathing4|4congratz4|4crisp4|4curse4| |\.]+$/',$s,$m);
```

you need to remove "^"  it will gives you the match which start with